# mediafire scraper get download_link

Tags: python, web, web-crawler

I have made a python script thats basically web crawler .
My aim is to get direct download links of files from some blogspot and then find-out direct download link.

```
def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page=1
    i=1
    while page < max_pages:
        url='http://comicsmegacity.blogspot.in/'
        source_code=requests.get(url)
        plain_text=source_code.text
        soup=BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findAll('a' , href=re.compile('http://www\.mediafire\.com/')):

            href=link.get('href')
            print('link no ' + str(i) +'    title   ' + link.string)
            i+=1
            print(href)
            get_download_link(href)
        page+=1

def get_download_link(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source_code.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
    for link in soup.findAll('div', {"class": "download_link"}):
        href = link.get('href')
        print('Download link ')
        print(href)


trade_spider(2)
```

But the output:

```
link no 1    title   Prem Ritu
http://www.mediafire.com/download/1vkgv8i0a151vqm/Prem+Ritu-1.pdf
Download link 
None

Download link 
None
link no 2    title   Kobi Prem
http://www.mediafire.com/download/b46y4fe61cgyfts/kobi+prem-2.pdf
Download link 
None
Download link 
None
```

Answer (score 0):

If they revealed their direct download link, they wouldn't have any business.

They hide it through their JavaScript, so that their direct link isn't revealed through ordinary **scraping** methods. Try selenium with headless approach.

Here is an [article](https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/) that you can read, that will render javascript.

Here is the code that actually works:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("http://www.mediafire.com/download/1vkgv8i0a151vqm/Prem+Ritu-1.pdf")
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('download_link')
print div.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Yaah i know but i get download link simple webpage where it is present for example http://www.mediafire.com/download/1vkgv8i0a151vqm/Prem+Ritu-1.pdf

Comment: thats not download link. it's a link to a direct download link.

Comment: ya i know but when we do inspect element then we can find direct download link

Comment: because your browser rendered the JavaScript already. the library `requests` is not capable of rendering JavaScript.

Comment: its shows first you are are using print with brackets i did it right second

Comment: File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py", line 78, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver: %s" % e)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified